# Multiple Forms For One Database

Tags: sqlite, wxpython, multiple-instances

I have a database containing just over 100 tables.  I have developed multiple summary forms to access various related tables.  I now want to build a overview form to specify a search which will then pull up the related record on the various summary forms. [Child Parent Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHENB.jpg)
The image attached is from the original MS Access database but shows how the main form references several summary forms.
Presently each form opens a self.db = Sqlite3.connect("PipeSpec.db") and self.cursor = self.db.cursor().  Is there a simple way to pass this connection to other forms, I am concerned this will turn into a memory hog, will that be the case?

Comment: If each `form` is a `class` pass it `parent=self`. In the `form` class, set `self.db = parent.db`. (Remember not to close it in that `class`)

Comment: Thanks I was looking at using flatnotebook to solve the problem, not as eligant.  I'll do more follow up and give this a try